# Difference between hyperparameter and hyperparameter-tuning tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

It seems that there are two similar tags: `hyperparameter` and `hyperparameter-tuning` (see below)

[image]

Both tags are used at relatively the same rate and could potentially be merged. I see 2 options here:

- Keep both tags

This would imply that they pertain to different topics. If this is the case, someone should write a clear description for `hyperparameter-tuning` as it is currently missing.

- Merge both tags

My personal preference. What is the process for merging tags? Are only users with a certain reputation allowed to perform that action? Is there a way to suggest merging tags besides asking a question like I did here?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can merge tags when you have enough total reputation and a positive answer score for the tag under consideration. A positive answer score is sufficient to vote on tag synonyms.

`hyperparameter` seems to be more general than `hyperparameter-tuning`, for example, it could include questions about parameters of a Bayesian prior distribution.